# Embedding a Notion link into a React App so that it is not a plain URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question is slightly different from others posted where I see they want to embed an entire notion page into their website. I would just like to embed a Notion link so that it doesn't look like a plain URL. Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: A link is a link. If you don't want it to look like a URL, you probably want the `<a>` tag and perhaps some css?

Comment: I was thinking the same way you can embed a tweet or twitter account and you can embed that link so it's not a plain URL. Twitter has something for that. I was wondering if there is something similar I could do for Notion

Comment: That sounds more like a notion support question than a programming question then. The twitter 'embed tweet' feature works simply by copying some HTML. If notion has that feature, ask them. If they don't, you need to make something custom with css.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.